# Java try/catch return jumps outside if statement?

Tags: java, android

The following code returns null without raising an exception when contactMap is not null and not empty.

```
    private List<Contact> getParseQuery(final Map<String, Contact> contactMap) {
        if (contactMap != null && !contactMap.isEmpty()) {
            // removed some code here to make this easier to spot
            try {
                List<Person> people = mainQuery.find();
                for (Person person : people) {
                    Contact contact = contactMap.get(person.getPhone());
                    contact.setUser(person);
                    contacts.add(contact);
                }
                return contacts;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Why does this return null? I stepped though this code with one piece of data in the "people" list. After the first time though, it goes back to the "for" statement to check if there are more people in the list, then the next line returns null inside the "else"? How is this even possible? No exception are raised.

Comment: Are you sure you are debugging on a matching version of the source file?

Comment: why don't just try dumping out put to debug before if statement

Comment: Are you certain it's actually returning `null`? It's possible to appear that way due to code flow control though the lower level byte code could have "contacts" in the return location while the program pointer looks like it's at "return null". Step out of the function and see what actually got returned if you haven't already done this.

Comment: Clean your project and restart adb server before debugging again

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily trust that a debugger knows which of the two `return null` statements is being executed, especially if an optimization has rearranged the code so that there's actually only one `return null` in the byte code.  I'd try putting a `System.out.println` before each `return` to find out for sure where the program is going.

Comment: Regarding the debugger line-jumping, see "known issues and limitations" in http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/debugger.html .  (I think there's a similar note in some of the "official" docs, but I can't find it right now.)

Comment: It does not print a stack trace. Yes, the source file is matching since I just successfully uploaded it to my android phone and I verified it. :) I'm going to try adding print statements!

Comment: So looks like it wasn't actually returning null, @mah was correct! Thanks!